# How to continuously pull data from a URL in Python?

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a link, e.g. [www.someurl.com/api/getdata?password=...](http://www.someurl.com/api/getdata?password=...), and when I open it in a web browser it sends a constantly updating document of text. I'd like to make an identical connection in Python, and dump this data to a file live as it's received. I've tried using `requests.Session()`, but since the stream of data never ends (and dropping it would lose data), the get request also never ends.

```
import requests

s = requests.Session()
x = s.get("www.someurl.com/api/getdata?password=...") #never terminates
```

What's the proper way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried using `with open() as f` to stream the data to a file?

Comment: what do you mean by never terminates ? can you explain more

Comment: @sbabtizied It's a continuous stream of data, so by design it should never halt. I'd like to always keep the connection alive, but to be able to access the data it's pulled without killing it.

Comment: check the answer that i have written, you can terminate the process , manipulate the data and then do the same thing again in a while loop (yes you will loose some data but it's  not a big deal after all you are dealing with infine amount of data )

Comment: @sbabtizied isn't that also wasteful, as it needs to continuously re-establish the connection? And losing data is very undesirable when it seems to just be a matter of finding the right method to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer I was looking for here: [Python Requests Stream Data from API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57497833/python-requests-stream-data-from-api)

Full implementation:

```
import requests

url = "www.someurl.com/api/getdata?password=..."
s = requests.Session()
with open('file.txt','a') as fp:
    with s.get(url,stream=True) as resp:
        for line in resp.iter_lines(chunk_size=1):
            fp.write(str(line))
```

Note that `chunk_size=1` is necessary for the data to immediately respond to new complete messages, rather than waiting for an internal buffer to fill before iterating over all the lines. I believe `chunk_size=None` is meant to do this, but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep making get requests to the url

```
import requests
import time

url = "www.someurl.com/api/getdata?password=..."

sess = requests.session()
while True:
    req = sess.get(url)
    time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: The problem here is that get request never terminates, by design it sends out live data. If I manually kill the connection it has all the data up to that point, but I can't access it until I kill it, and that also losses out on data.

Comment: Maybe you could write it to a file or even sqlite?

Answer (score 0):

this will terminate the request after 1 second ,

```
import multiprocessing
import time
import requests

data = None

def get_from_url(x):
    s = requests.Session() 
    data = s.get("www.someurl.com/api/getdata?password=...")    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True: 
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=get_from_url, name="get_from_url", args=(1,))
        p.start()

        # Wait 1 second for get request
        time.sleep(1)

        p.terminate()

        p.join()
        
        # do something with the data 
        print(data) # or smth else
```

Comment: memory (and so: variables) are not shared between processes so printing `data` won't work (I mean it will always print `None`) and it also wouldn't work because you change `data` only in the scope of the function

Comment: you can do the work inside the function get_from_url in this case (there is always a solution)