# Download files as stream without downloading complete files into memory

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, stream, gzipstream

I want to download files as stream from a remote server and make them zip stream and return it to frontend as stream without waiting all files to complete downloads.

Is it possible in python and framework of python ??
I tried as below but its not working i am using Django framework:

```
 zip_buffer = io.BytesIO()

 with zipstream.ZipFile(zip_buffer,"w", zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED, False) as zf:
     url = "https://download-file/zy"
     r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
     zip_inf = zipstream.ZipInfo(file_name)
     zf.write_iter(zip_inf, r.content)
response = StreamingHttpResponse(zip_buffer.getvalue(), content_type='application/octet-stream')
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=zip-files.zip'
            return response
```

Comment: Part of the issue that you didn't loop over the data received from the requests library.

Comment: like you want me to read r file stream and send it to the zip ?

Comment: Something like the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57498146/871410

Comment: i tried and got "ValueError: stat: embedded null character in path" error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried by using aiozipstream and fast api for streamingResponse. this solution worked for me.

```
 files = []
 urls = ['url1','ur2']
 for url in urls:
    files.append({'stream': file_content_generator(url), 'name': url.split('/')[-1]})
 zf = ZipStream(files, chunksize=32768)

 response = StreamingResponse(zf.stream(), media_type='application/zip')
    return response

def file_content_generator(url):
     with httpx.stream('GET', url, timeout=None) as r:
          yield from r.iter_bytes()
```